# how to save image in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_no= models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    shop_name=models.CharField(max_length=244, null=True)
    shop_address=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    abn=models.CharField(max_length=11)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    #last_4_digits = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=False)
    #stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=False)
    #subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    Emg_no=models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
    area_code=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=2)
    landline_number= models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=9)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    status=models.ForeignKey(Status,blank=True,null=True)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_image')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.first_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'registration_userprofile'
```

I want to save image separately so that I write a form

```
class User_imageForm(forms.Form):
    user_image = forms.ImageField(required= False)
    class Meta:
        model=UserProfile
        Fields=('user_image')
```

Now i want to save the image at given path, my view is

```
    @login_required(login_url="/registration/login/") 
def user_image(request,user_id):
    print("start of user_image view")
    server1 = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    print("hiiiiiiiiiiiii")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post ")
        userimage = User_imageForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if userimage.is_valid():
            print("form is valid")
            server1.user_image=userimage.cleaned_data['user_image']
            server1.save()
            print("image save")
            print(request.user.id)

            variables=RequestContext(request,
                               {'id':request.user.id})
            return redirect('updatedetails', int(request.user.id) )

        else:
            print("form is not valid") 
            userimage = User_imageForm() 
            return render_to_response('registration/profile_try.html')
```

Comment: You need to use `upload_to` attribute of `ImageField` like this: `user_image = forms.ImageField(upload_to='your_path_here', required=False)`

Comment: i have added upload_to attribute

Comment: Does it work now?